# What's the easiest way to do form validation for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms, jquery-events

All I want to do is to check if the textfield has been changed. If not, I want to highlight the boxes when submit is pressed. How do I do that? Seems very simple, but not sure why every other solution is so complicated.

Comment: see the updates! and let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building upon Pim's answer, you can associate the `changed` flag for each text field using jQuery's data API.

```
// initially, assign changed to false for all text fields
$("input:text").data("changed", false);

// if any field changes, set its changed flag to true
$("input:text").change(function() {
    $(this).data("changed", true);
}

// finally on submission, get all text fields that did not
//  change by checking their "changed" property
var unchangedItems = $("input:text").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("changed") === false;
});
```

Comment: way better then my global flag idea. nice solution!

Comment: be aware that changing an input's value with javascript doesn't fire the `changed` event

Comment: @Andrew Bullock - yes, but you CAN put a $('fieldIChanged').trigger("change"); on it when you DO change it that way :) where 'fieldIChanged' is the selector for that item (this?)

Comment: @Mark really? oo ill investigate that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin.

Comment: ooo! New version! 1.7 is jQuery 1.42 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Bassicly, you just say it has never been changed, and when it cahnges, you set a flag saying is has been changed:

```
var changed = false;
$('#textfield').change(function(){
    changed = true;
});
if(changed){
    $('.textbox').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('.highlighted');
        //or something like this, whatever you want to do to highlight them
    });
}
```